# create array with a different variable/value depending on each <div> id and class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way with JS/JQuery to create an array with a different variable for each of the following specific elements in my page?

```
<div id#1-hello></div>
<div id#2-hello></div>
...etc
```

and give them a value depending on the class name attached to that element? (for instance if the class name is count-2 value will be 2)

Right what I'm doing is not really efficient as I'm repeating a lot of my functions, and have to manually add more whenever I want to add new html elements:

```js
 var pets = ["Error", "Fish", "Wolf", "Whale", "Zebra", "Ferret"];
     
var petClass = $('#1-fish').hasClass('petClass')
switch(petClass) {
case 'count-0':
  pets[1] = 0;
  break;
case 'count-1':
  pets[1] = 1;
  break;
case 'count-2':
  pets[1] = 2;
  break;
case 'count-3':
  pets[1] = 3;
  break;
  default:
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1-fish" class="map-marker count-0"></div>
    <div id="2-wolf" class="map-marker count-2"></div>
    <div id="3-whale" class="map-marker count-3"></div>
    <div id="4-zebra" class="map-marker count-1"></div>
    <div id="5-ferret" class="map-marker count-1"></div>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, but this question is too broad

Comment: Did you try anything to solve this on your own? Like selecting the elements with the class `.map-marker` and then work with their ids and classes (and maybe some `.split()` and/or regex action)?

Comment: Your `.hasClass` is referencing `'petClass'`, but that doesn't appear in your HTML anywhere?

Comment: willman, yeah this is a mistake from me when simplifying my issue in order to post it here, sorry.

controlaltdel, i felt i was my exemple was specific enough but i'll edit some details.

@andreas i'm stuck with this, i cannot figure out how to create new variable in the same array for each of the <div> elements, maybe i'm not "wording" my searches correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is a bit vague.  Are you looking for something like this?

```
var pets = ["Error", "Fish", "Wolf", "Whale", "Zebra", "Ferret"];
var petCounts = {};

pets.each(function (pet) {
  var petCountDivs = $('[id$="'+pet+'"]').find('petClass');
  petCountDivs.each(function () {
    var countClass = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/).find(function(maybeCountClass) { 
      return maybeCountClass.startsWith("count");
    }
    var petCount = countClass.substring(countClass.lastIndexOf('-'));
    if (petCounts[pet]) {
      petCounts[pet] += petCount;
    } else{
      petCounts[pet] = petCount;
    }
  });
});
```

This first uses the `$=` selector to find elements whose `'id'` attribute "ends with" the specified petname from the `pets` array, then uses `.find('petClass')` on those elements, so that `var petCountDivs` is a collection of all the elements that are inside pet-named divs that have the `petClass` class.

Then looping through each of those `petCountDivs`, it grabs the name of the class that starts with the word "count", and parses the value that comes after the dash ('-'), then either creates a new count object or aggregates to the existing counter that parsed value.